# Реализвация личных сообщений Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

Есть чат, на qtcpserver и qtcpsocket соответственно, клиент нажимает отправить сообщение видно всем, как реализовать сообщения отдельному пользователю?

Comment: клиент делает запрос на сервер на получение сообщения и передает свое имя, если имя подходящее, то сервер вернет клиенту сообщение, а если имя не совпало, то вернется 0